# Bibtex parser in Rails; Can get gem to work in console but not app itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, latex, bibtex

I'm building an app wherein I want to parse bibtex into citations in html.  I used the [CiteProc-Ruby](https://github.com/inukshuk/citeproc-ruby) and [bibtex-ruby](https://github.com/inukshuk/bibtex-ruby) gems to implement this.

I used this gem.  I tried the following code in the Rails console.

```
cp = CiteProc::Processor.new style: 'apa', format: 'text'
cp.import BibTeX.open('sources.bib').to_citeproc
```

This works fine.  The cp object is a hash of references parsed from the sources.bib file, and with this has I can render html citations in APA or some other format.

So now I want to use this in my app.  So I added this to application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  @cp = CiteProc::Processor.new style: 'apa', format: 'text'
  @cp.import BibTeX.open('sources.bib').to_citeproc
end
```

My expectation was to use the @cp object in the views.  But instead I get this error message:

> uninitialized constant ApplicationController::CiteProc

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`require 'citeproc'` should do it. Generally just adding citeproc to your Gemfile should require it (assuming you're using a default Rails setup)